# Login Facebook in android not working

Tags: java, android, facebook, authentication

I trying implements Facebook in my app Android but when a write my mail and password of Facebook no print "Dentro1" or "Dentro2" or "Dentro3". Why?

Thank you!!

```
callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager,
        new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                System.out.println("Dentro1");
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                System.out.println("Dentro2");
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                System.out.println("Dentro3");
            }

        });
```

Comment: Do you get any exceptions? Can you show us the output?

Answer (score 1):

You need to do like below..

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

And..start login with some permissions what you want.

```
LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(this, Arrays.asList("user_friends"));
```